# JMS component's bridge error handler not working

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-jms

As per apache camel's documentation, JMS component supports bridging with camel error handlers, but while executing I am getting "BridgeErrorHandler is not support on JMS endpoint".
I checked their source code and found while creating jms consumers, this flag is checked and if found true an IllegalArgumentException is thrown with above message.

Can anyone help me out in this regard ?

Note: I am using apache camel 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

`bridgeErrorHandler` option is not supported on JMS and ActiveMQ component ([CAMEL-14083](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14083)). We will fix documentation in [CAMEL-15001](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-15001).

Comment: Thank you @Bedla for raising the JIRA. Btw, regarding the comment by Claus in CAMEL-14083, I suspect enablng eagerLoadingOfProperties will incur a performance hit. Is there any other way to know whether JMS consumers are stuck or not ?