# Exception not getting handled by onException(Throwable.class) after enabling bridgeErrorHandler on SEDA

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have following route

```
onException(Throwable.class)
.handled(true)
.process(...)                              --- (A1) Have a shutdown code here.
.rollback();

from("file:D/data/input?fileName=in.txt")
.transacted("required")                    --- (A2) Have JPA Txn Manager and hikari pooled datasource behind the scene
.split(...)
.to("seda:DUMMY?blockWhenFull=true");

from("seda:DUMMY?bridgeErrorHandler=true")
.transacted("required")                    --- (A3) Creating new transaction due to SEDA
.process(...)                              --- (A4) reading from database and doing some computation
.to("file:D:/data/ouput?fileName=out.txt")
```

I managed to shutdown DB in between processing the file (in.txt) and so HikariDataSource started throwing exceptions. However, even after enabling the bridgeErrorHandler on SEDA consumer side, these exceptions were not getting handled by onException() clause. 
In logs, I found that these exceptions are simply logged by TransactionErrorHandler. Could you please help how to trigger onException() in this case, so that the application can shutdown?

Please find the logs below:

```
2020-06-10 18:25:14,314 WARN com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection [157] [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - file://D:/data/input] -[TEST1]-[RW_TEST_ROUTE_2]-[3019]-[]- HikariPool-1 - Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@6eeade6c marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(17002)
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doCommit(T4CConnection.java:965) ~[ojdbc7-customized-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:2401) ~[ojdbc7-customized-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:2407) ~[ojdbc7-customized-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.commit(ProxyConnection.java:366) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.commit(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar!/:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar!/:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar!/:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:534) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:744) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:712) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.doInTransactionTemplate(TransactionErrorHandler.java:182) ~[camel-spring-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processInTransaction(TransactionErrorHandler.java:140) ~[camel-spring-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:107) ~[camel-spring-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:116) ~[camel-spring-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:228) ~[camel-base-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.doProcess(Pipeline.java:103) ~[camel-base-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.lambda$process$1(Pipeline.java:87) ~[camel-base-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$3.run(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:116) [camel-base-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:185) [camel-base-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59) [camel-base-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:87) [camel-base-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:228) [camel-base-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:454) [camel-file-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:223) [camel-file-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:186) [camel-file-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:183) [camel-support-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102) [camel-support-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_251]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:209) ~[ojdbc7-customized-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:215) ~[ojdbc7-customized-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:302) ~[ojdbc7-customized-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:249) ~[ojdbc7-customized-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:171) ~[ojdbc7-customized-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:89) ~[ojdbc7-customized-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123) ~[ojdbc7-customized-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79) ~[ojdbc7-customized-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineStream.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineStream.java:429) ~[ojdbc7-customized-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:397) ~[ojdbc7-customized-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257) ~[ojdbc7-customized-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOCOMMIT(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:73) ~[ojdbc7-customized-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doCommit(T4CConnection.java:910) ~[ojdbc7-customized-12.1.0.2.0.jar!/:12.1.0.2.0]
    ... 35 more
2020-06-10 18:25:14,318 WARN org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler [276] [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - file://D:/data/input] -[TEST1]-[RW_TEST_ROUTE_2]-[3019]-[]- Transaction rollback (0x21f9764) redelivered(false) for (MessageId: ID-RAJUP-1591793597060-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-RAJUP-1591793597060-0-2) caught: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection
2020-06-10 18:25:14,319 WARN org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion [144] [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - file://D:/data/input] -[TEST1]-[RW_TEST_ROUTE_2]-[3019]-[RW_TEST_ROUTE_2-1]- Rollback file strategy: org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy@6834b2f3 for file: GenericFile[D:\data\input\in.txt]
2020-06-10 18:25:27,306 WARN org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [137] [Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - seda://ADPIN] -[TEST1]-[RW_TEST_ROUTE_2]-[3019]-[RW_TEST_ROUTE_2-4]- SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2020-06-10 18:25:27,306 ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [142] [Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - seda://ADPIN] -[TEST1]-[RW_TEST_ROUTE_2]-[3019]-[RW_TEST_ROUTE_2-4]- HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
2020-06-10 18:25:27,307 WARN org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler [276] [Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - seda://ADPIN] -[TEST1]-[RW_TEST_ROUTE_2]-[3019]-[RW_TEST_ROUTE_2-4]- Transaction rollback (0x21f9764) redelivered(false) for (MessageId: ID-RAJUP-1591793597060-0-140 on ExchangeId: ID-RAJUP-1591793597060-0-5227) caught: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I found the reason of above behaviour:

Enabling bridgeErrorHandler on SEDA consumers or any capable consumers tells the error handler (in our case TransactionErrorHandler, not the OnException() clause) to handle the exception. ErrorHandlers are the last resort i.e if any exception doesn't get catched by OnException() clause, then error handlers will be there to handle that.
As the name 'bridgeErrorHandler' implies bridging with error handlers, so any exception during message consumption (in our case from SEDA) will directly trigger the error handlers.
Thanks to 'exceptionHandler' parameter of SEDA consumer side url to given a hook to achieve our desired functionality.

NOTE: JMS consumer side url used to have 'bridgeErrorHandler' option, but after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578332/jms-components-bridge-error-handler-not-working), it got removed.